# How do I find the primitive of $f(x)=arctanx^2+arccotanx^2$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x^2)+\cot^{-1}(x^2)$. I need to find the primitive function of $f$.
Now, I know that f is a constant function, because its $f'(x)=0$. And I think that let's say if $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is its primitive then $F'(x)=f(x)$ which means that $F'(x)$ needs also to be a constant. I think I managed to solve it $\int \tan^{-1}(x^2)+\cot^{-1}(x^2)dx=\int \frac{\pi}{2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}x+C$, am I right?

Comment: $$\arctan(x^2)$$ or $$(\arctan(x))^2$$

Comment: Try evaluating $f$ at some convenient $x$ value to see what the constant is.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $arctan(x^2)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael And what I do after? $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: try Integration by parts

Comment: Hint: $$\arctan(x^2) = \frac \pi 2 - \operatorname{arccot}(x^2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

From,

$$\tan(x^2) = \operatorname{cot}\left(\frac \pi 2 - x^2\right)$$

We have,

$$\arctan(x^2) = \frac \pi 2 - \operatorname{arccot}(x^2)$$

Hence,

$$\int (\arctan(x^2) + \operatorname{arccot}(x^2)) \mathrm dx = \int \left(\frac \pi 2 - \operatorname{arccot}(x^2) + \operatorname{arccot}(x^2)\right)\mathrm dx $$

Which is quite easy to evaluate,

$$\int \frac \pi 2 \mathrm dx = \frac \pi 2 x + C$$

**Proof of first line**

$$\operatorname{cot}\left(\frac \pi 2 - x^2\right) = \frac{\cos\left(\frac \pi 2 - x^2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac \pi 2 - x^2\right)} = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{\cos(x^2)} = \tan(x^2)$$

Comment: A little technicality: your first implication is not necessarily right because the functions $\tan$ and $\cot$ are not invertible and you have to choose a branch. In this case, with the usual conventions, you are safe.

Comment: You're right, but my use of $\operatorname{arccot}$ and $\arctan$ should make clear what branch was chosen. Your deleted answer did remind of me of the discontinuity at $x = 0$ that I stupidly missed, I'll address that now.

Comment: I deleted after noticing that the argument is always positive :-) But I wanted to remind that identities like $\tan a=\tan b$ can't be blindly turned to $a=b$ nor $\arctan a=\arctan b$.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking of that at the time, I was more thinking of substituting a suitable $x^2$ to make sure that the argument of $\tan$/$\operatorname{cot}$ lied in the "principal range". Odd because I'm normally the one to pick up on said technicalities. Thanks for the shout :)